# Where are these strange subsites coming from in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, web

I received an automatic upgrade email from my Wordpress site. However, the subsite (instead of `www`) was `wffff88ff8wwf95ef8`. When logging into Akismet to renew my subscription, I see that it has the same subsite as an active subscription. That subsite is obviously not valid and is not in my webserver config. Any idea where this is coming from?

[image: wrong subsite]

I'm running this on a LEMP server. Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx, MariaDB, PHP7. The box is pretty locked down, so I don't think I'm "hacked" (but who knows).

Comment: Have you checked your database if home and wordpress url (usually with the first 40 options of an installations) are set correctly?

Comment: @Blackbam, yes, they are set correctly.

Comment: Deactivate all Plugins (one by one) to check if a Plugin is causing the trouble. What is the result? Are the links in e-mails still wrong with plain wordpress only?